# Vim: Configure vim to show autocomplete suggestions from current open files

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I had this vim configuration some time back which shows autocomplete suggestions on pressing `Ctrl + N` from all the files I have opened during a session, not just the current file I am editing. Unfortunately I lost the vimrc and now I can't figure out what was making it do so.

Searched over internet and found results related to `omnicomplete`. But I didn't understand how it works. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I use [supertab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) that does this kind of code completion using `tab`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `:help i_ctrl-n`:

```
CTRL-N    Find next match for words that start with the
          keyword in front of the cursor, looking in places
          specified with the 'complete' option.  The found
          keyword is inserted in front of the cursor.
```

From `:help 'complete'` (or `<C-]>` on `'complete'`):

```
     b    scan other loaded buffers that are in the buffer list
```

**Don't google, *:help.***